# Rendering components only if they can fit inside a flex container

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I am trying to build a toolbar that hides components from the right if there is not enough space to render them. My approach is to use refs and add up the width and render based on the condition if the total width has been overflowed. I want to get something working and go on improving it from there. It seems to work 'ok' when the screen size is decreased but not when trying to 're-render' the components when there is room. I suspect adding a display style of 'none' is causing some of the issues.

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    this.littleFunction();
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.littleFunction);
  }

  littleFunction = () => {
    let sofar = 0;
    for (const ref in this.refs) {
      sofar += this.refs[ref].offsetWidth;
      const index = ref.indexOf('test');
      console.log(ref, sofar, this.input.offsetWidth);
      if (sofar > this.input.offsetWidth && index === -1) {
        this.refs[ref].style.display = 'none';
      }


      // // console.log(typeof this.refs[ref].style.display, this.refs[ref].style.display);
      // if (this.refs[ref] !== this.input) {
      //   sofar = this.refs[ref].offsetWidth + sofar;
      // }
      // const index = ref.indexOf('test');
      // // console.log(sofar, this.input.offsetWidth, index);
      // if (sofar >= this.input.offsetWidth && index === -1) {
      //   this.refs[ref].style.display = 'none';
      //
      //   this.forceUpdate();
      // } else if (sofar < this.input.offsetWidth && index === -1) {
      //   // console.log('inhiaaa', sofar, this.input.offsetWidth);
      //   this.refs[ref].style.display = '';
      //
      //   this.forceUpdate();
      // }
    }
  }
```

After thinking about this for a while, i realized that if i set the style to display: 'none', the next time I try to run this logic to check how many components can fit, I am actually not getting the length back from the components that were previously set to display: 'none'. What I did was save the width of the components before applying calling the function.

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    this.widths = new List();
    for (const ref in this.refs) {
      this.widths = this.widths.push(Map({
        name: ref,
        length: this.refs[ref].offsetWidth,
      }));
    }

    this.littleFunction();
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.littleFunction);
  }

  littleFunction = () => {
    let sofar = 0;
    this.widths.forEach(item => {
      sofar += item.get('length');
      const index = item.get('name').indexOf('test');

      if (sofar > this.input.offsetWidth && index === -1) {
        this.refs[item.get('name')].style.display = 'none';
          // this.forceUpdate();
      } else if (index === -1) {
        this.refs[item.get('name')].style.display = 'inline';
          // this.forceUpdate();
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have the toolbar to have style `{ width: '100%', overflow: 'hidden', whiteSpace: 'nowrap' }` should give you the desired effect.

Comment: Not sure what exactly what you are trying to do but another way I can think of is to instead of setting child style to `display: none`, you may set it to `height: 0, overflow: hidden` to hide but preserve width